# Subgroup of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am stuck on this problem and cannot seem to find a good reason for drawing the required conclusion. The problem is as follows:

> I know that the maximal dimension of abelian Lie subalgebra of
> $Lie(Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})=C_n$: symplectic Lie algebra equal to
> $k:=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$,  is this mean that the maximal dimension of
> abelian subgroup of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is $k$?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes by the subgroups-subalgebras theorem. Any subalgebra corresponds to a subgroup of the same dimension and vice versa. It is not hard to show that either being abelian means the other one is too

Comment: @Callum thank you ... for $Lie(Sp(2n,\mathbb{R}))=C_n$ i think it is not true.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't true?

Comment: @Callum I found out that $C_n$ is Lie algebra of $Sp$ over the complex number, which is why I think this may be a problem, and also I found it hard to construct an abelian subgroup of dimension $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ in $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your first sentence there. $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is indeed of type $C_n$ but this doesn't say anything about the maximal dimension of abelian subgroups/algebras a priori. As to the second, the subgroup is precisely the image under the exponential map of the subalgebra (this works because the subalgebra consists of only nilpotent elements so the exponential map restricts to an isomorphism in this case).

Comment: @Callum I know that $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is of type $C_n$, which is the Lie algebra of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$ but what about $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ can we say that the maximal dimension of abelian subalgebra in $Lie(Sp(2n,\mathbb{R}))$ is $k$.

Comment: In both cases the maximal dimension of an abelian subalgebra/subgroup is $k$ (of course meaning dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ respectively)